# How to define a variable globally in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to set a value globally but not able to solve. Here is my code

declared variable - `allViewounters: any[] = [];`

```
viewgraph() { 
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
                 
    this.profileService.lineChartData(formData).subscribe((response) => {
        this.allViewounters = response.allViewounters;
        console.log(this.allViewounters);
    });
}
```

I want to print the value outside the function `console.log(this.allViewounters);`

How can I get the value? I tried to get the value through "storageService" but in 1st load, it is not any giving value, for 2nd load it works fine, but I need in 1st page load.

Comment: Since response passed from .subscribe() is a callback, you can wrap it as a Promise that resolves to `repsonse.allViewounters`. Make your function asynchronous and access the value by calling the function with await.

Comment: Hii @lambda23 Thanks for your Reply. I am not getting what to do, will you please help me code-wise, I am new in  Typescript. waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

So the condition that you have right now is that you have a callback function that needs to get passed as variable on `subscribe()`. Since you want to pass the callback result somewhere else (outside `viewgraph()`), you can set an outside variable to the result that you're getting (what you have done). However, the variable will only be set if the callback has been called (the condition that you have right now).

However, you want to access the value once the callback is done. There is a way in JS/TS to "wait" for a result, by wrapping it in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for the result. So let's say the library has this method:

```
function subscribe (callbackFn: (response: any) => void) {
  // Assuming response gets passed from somewhere else
  callbackFn(response);
}
```

However, you want to wait for this callback to be called. You can wrap the way you handle the result by using Promise in an asynchronous function:

```
async function viewgraph() {
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.profileService
      .lineChartData(formData)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      }
  });
}
```

and then on whatever function that you want to obtain the result, call this function with `await`, like:

```
const response = await viewgraph();
```

Keep in mind that whatever function that calls an await needs to be asynchronous too (marked as `async`, just like `viewgraph()`).

If you want to learn more about promise handling and async/await, [read this article](https://javascript.info/async).